# Print table pdf feature

Tags: php

This is my index on showing the report of the inventory system

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport">

  <title>Inventory Management System</title>
    

<?php
    session_start();
  if(!isset($_SESSION['login_id']))
    header('location:login.php');
 include('./header.php'); 
 // include('./auth.php'); 
 ?>

</head>
<style>
    body{
        background: #80808045;
  }
</style>

<body>
    <?php include 'topbar.php' ?>
    <?php include 'navbar.php' ?>
  <div class="toast" id="alert_toast" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
    <div class="toast-body text-white">
    </div>
  </div>
  <main id="view-panel" >
      <?php $page = isset($_GET['page']) ? $_GET['page'] :'home'; ?>
    <?php include $page.'.php' ?>
    

  </main>

  <div id="preloader"></div>
  <a href="#" class="back-to-top"><i class="icofont-simple-up"></i></a>

<div class="modal fade" id="confirm_modal" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div id="delete_content"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='confirm' onclick="">Continue</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="modal fade" id="uni_modal" role='dialog'>
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-md" role="document">
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title"></h5>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id='submit' onclick="$('#uni_modal form').submit()">Save</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
      </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
<script>
     window.start_load = function(){
    $('body').prepend('<di id="preloader2"></di>')
  }
  window.end_load = function(){
    $('#preloader2').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
  }

  window.uni_modal = function($title = '' , $url=''){
    start_load()
    $.ajax({
        url:$url,
        error:err=>{
            console.log()
            alert("An error occured")
        },
        success:function(resp){
            if(resp){
                $('#uni_modal .modal-title').html($title)
                $('#uni_modal .modal-body').html(resp)
                $('#uni_modal').modal('show')
                end_load()
            }
        }
    })
}
window._conf = function($msg='',$func='',$params = []){
     $('#confirm_modal #confirm').attr('onclick',$func+"("+$params.join(',')+")")
     $('#confirm_modal .modal-body').html($msg)
     $('#confirm_modal').modal('show')
  }
   window.alert_toast= function($msg = 'TEST',$bg = 'success'){
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-success')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-danger')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-info')
      $('#alert_toast').removeClass('bg-warning')

    if($bg == 'success')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-success')
    if($bg == 'danger')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-danger')
    if($bg == 'info')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-info')
    if($bg == 'warning')
      $('#alert_toast').addClass('bg-warning')
    $('#alert_toast .toast-body').html($msg)
    $('#alert_toast').toast({delay:3000}).toast('show');
  }
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#preloader').fadeOut('fast', function() {
        $(this).remove();
      })
  })
</script>   
</html>
```

And this is the table names in database.
[database table names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tDxm8.png)

I know how I can make a print button but I do not know how to make it process. How can I add the feature that can print the data in table form and pdf? Sorry for asking, just a newbie.

Comment: paraphrase you question, please as your quesitons is not 100% clear. Do you want to get some data from DB, then output it and generate a pdf file from it?

Comment: Yes that one. Sorry for the unclear question

Comment: you can use [dompdf](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf)